# Pass list of values to be inserted as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this stored procedure in MySQL version 5.7. If I want to create n elements it would be much faster to insert n elements in one statement two times rather than call the stored procedure n times.

How can I create a stored procedure that takes a "list" of names, a team id and does this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_data_user(IN name VARCHAR(100), IN data_user_team_id INT)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO users (users.name, users.type)
VALUES (name, "team_data");
INSERT INTO team_members (team_id, user_id, mod_time)
VALUES (data_user_team_id, LAST_INSERT_ID(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
COMMIT;
END ;;
```

A stored procedure that creates two elements would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_data_user(IN name VARCHAR(100), IN name2 VARCHAR(100), IN 
data_user_team_id INT)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO users (users.name, users.type)
VALUES 
(name, "team_data"),
(name2, "team_data");
INSERT INTO team_members (team_id, user_id, mod_time)
VALUES 
(data_user_team_id, LAST_INSERT_ID(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),
(data_user_team_id, LAST_INSERT_ID()+1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
COMMIT;
END ;;
```

Edit:
There are different ways to tackle this. You could just scrap the SP and copy-paste batch insert code. Rick James presented a complex solution, but I think you can do something simpler, perhaps at some cost in performance (but better than many individual inserts).

On the caller side you do something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE names (name);

INSERT INTO names
VALUES
(name1),
(name2),
...;

CALL create_data_users(1);
```

And then the stored procedure is like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_data_users(IN data_user_team_id INT)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO users (users.name, users.type) 
    SELECT name, "team_data" FROM names; 
    SET @num=LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
    INSERT INTO team_members (team_id, user_id, mod_time) 
    SELECT data_user_team_id, @num:=@num+1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM names;
COMMIT;
END ;;
```

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina version 5.7

Comment: Do you want to provide a list of names (separated by, for example, a comma) and one team id?

Comment: @Akina Yes, for example. Keep in mind there should only be a total of 2 insert statements in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best efficient generalization, especially for long lists, I have found is to

1. Build a temp table
2. Use a batch `INSERT` to populate the table
3. `INSERT ... SELECT ...` to get the items in the real table
4. Do a complex update with a join to pull back all the ids.

(No loops involved.)

Specifics:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization

(That is focused around the very likely situation where the names are already in the table.  However, it should work fine for your case.)

Comment: If the temp table only contains names, then I'm not sure how step 3 would be performed. If not, then at that point I think you might as well just scrap the stored procedure and copy and paste the code. Not sure how step 4 is done either, wouldn't you need a key from the temp table into the real table?

Comment: Yes, for a small number of rows, just copy the code.  Or, if practical, write a look in your application code.  It was unclear what you will be doing with the ids.  Is it possible that "name" is already in the table?

Comment: The ids from inserting into users is used when inserting into team_members. Yes, it's possible name already exists

Comment: @John - Then I don't think a simple `INSERT` or even `INSERT IGNORE` will get you the id.  Hence my code that first inserts them, _then_ fetches the ids.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean. I was thinking of something simple like this where names is a temporary table. Not sure how to pass the temp table as an argument though.

`INSERT INTO users (users.name, users.type)
SELECT name, "team_data" FROM names;
SET @num=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO team_members (team_id, user_id, mod_time)
SELECT data_user_team_id, @num:=@num+1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM names;`

Comment: I think the caller can just create the temporary table, batch insert names into it and then call the stored procedure with the team id.

Comment: I would not trust @variables, especially when assigning them in a Select.  Rumor has it that such will be removed from MySQL 8.0 soon.

Comment: @num:=@num+1 may get in trouble with any `name` that is already in the table.  (Another reason not to trust it.)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE create_data_users (IN users_list TEXT, IN data_user_team_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE name VARCHAR(255);
    REPEAT
        SET name = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(users_list, ',', 1));
        SET users_list = CASE WHEN LOCATE(',', users_list)
                              THEN TRIM(SUBSTRING(users_list FROM 1 + LOCATE(',', users_list)))
                              ELSE '' END;
        INSERT INTO users (users.name, users.type)
        VALUES (name, "team_data");
        INSERT INTO team_members (team_id, user_id, mod_time)
        VALUES (data_user_team_id, LAST_INSERT_ID(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
    UNTIL users_list = '' END REPEAT;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=37e397c1066e1e8459df70fc6131e5d4

Comment: Looks like this will execute 2 times n number of insert statements, so will it not be about as slow as calling the original stored procedure n times?

Comment: @John Of course, SP inserts the players one-by-one. There is no another way - you use `LAST_INSERT_ID` which must be generated and then reused separately for each separate user. Batch insertion (one INSERT per SP) is possible only if `users.name` is defined as unique and may be used for `users.ID` value retrieving.

Comment: It is possible if innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=1 (which it is for me). And also see here in the "important" box: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @John *It is possible if innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=1 (which it is for me).* ?? I don't understand what you tell about. Maybe this is current setting - but you shouldn't think that it is unchangeable... *And also see here in the "important" box* I already know that.

Comment: It is changeable, but only by me. I'm saying batch insertion is possible, see my edit. If nothing else I think you could build two SQL strings in the SP loop with the values and execute them as two statements. Btw how is it possible if users.name can be used for users.ID value retrieving?